# MS-Access VBA - How to assign the current query field name used by a textbox to a variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a form that obtains records from a query.

In this form I have some textboxes linked to the query fields.

I want to assign to a variable the current query field name used by a textbox on an `AfterUpdate` event like this:

```
Private Sub Texbox1_AfterUpdate()
Dim fldName as Stringf
fldName = Me.RecordSource.Textbox1.Field
End Sub
```

This doesn't work of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property that you require is [`ControlSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.controlsource).

For example:

```
Private Sub Texbox1_AfterUpdate()
    Dim fldName As String
    fldName = Textbox1.ControlSource
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Texbox1_AfterUpdate()
Dim fldName As String
fldName = Textbox1.Value
End Sub
```